# multiple tabs are not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using a jquery plugin for image annotation. I have multiple images in different tabs. I am using jquery tabs for this purpose but before that, I have used foundation tabs and was facing the same issue. 
here is my code

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang = "en">
  <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <script src="libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs functionality</title>
  <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">   </script>   
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="annotorious-0.6.4/css/annotorious.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="annotorious.min.js"></script>


  <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#tabs-1" ).tabs();
     });
  </script>

  <style>
     #tabs-1{font-size: 14px;}
     .ui-widget-header {
        background:#b9cd6d;
        border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
     }
  </style>

  </head>

   <body onload="init();">
     <div id = "tabs-1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href = "#tabs-2">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#tabs-3">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#tabs-4">Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>

       <div id = "tabs-2">
            <img id="myImage" src="pic2.jpg" style="border: 30px solid #ccc; padding:20px;" width="30%" height="30%" />
     </div>

     <div id = "tabs-3">
     <img id="myImage1" src="pic1.jpg" style="border: 30px solid #ccc; padding:20px;" width="30%" height="30%" />    
     </div>

     <div id = "tabs-4">
        <p>ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
           voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem   aperiam, 
           eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto 
           beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.  </p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
           sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
           Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
           nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
     </div>

     </div>
      <script>
       function init() {

       anno.makeAnnotatable(document.getElementById('myImage1'));
       anno.makeAnnotatable(document.getElementById('myImage'));
      }
        </script>

    </body>

     </html>
```

I want to make annotation on images. So here my jquery image annotation plugins work fine for the tab 1 (first image) but it's not working on the  tab 2 (second image) or any other tabs. Maybe this is related to javascript events, Plz help me.

Comment: What's the issue? Please be specific so we can attempt to recreate this. Also, check your browser's JS log for any errors. FYI: There's a space in `<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui- lightness/jquery-ui.css
     " rel = "stylesheet">`. Generally spaces aren't even accepted in URLs, so that might be part of your issue.

Comment: Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the spaces that Quangdao mentioned, you might also need to set jQuery into no-conflict mode per [their documentation](http://annotorious.github.io/getting-started.html). Also, you should move your init into the ready method instead of mixing it with the body's onload.

**Edit:** It appears that you also need to use a combination of the CSS-based initialization (adding `class="annotatable"` to your images) and the API to re-enable the annotation plugin upon tab switch. You can leverage the tab's `activate` event to do this:

```
  <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#tabs-1").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
          jQuery('img.annotatable', ui.newPanel).each(function() {
            anno.makeAnnotatable(this);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Demo below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs functionality</title>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://annotorious.github.io/latest/annotorious.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://annotorious.github.io/latest/annotorious.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    #tabs-1 {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .ui-widget-header {
      background: #b9cd6d;
      border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-2">
      <img id="myImage" class="annotatable" src="https://unsplash.it/g/200" style="border: 30px solid #ccc; padding:20px;" width="30%" height="30%" />
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
      <img id="myImage1" class="annotatable" src="https://unsplash.it/200" style="border: 30px solid #ccc; padding:20px;" width="30%" height="30%" />
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
      <p>ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#tabs-1").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
          jQuery('img.annotatable', ui.newPanel).each(function() {
            anno.makeAnnotatable(this);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit 2**: To save and reload from localstorage, you want to add event handlers for the `onAnnotationRemoved`, `onAnnotationCreated`, and `onAnnotationUpdated` to store it into localstorage when the annotations are created/modified/removed. To load the annotations on page load, I had to call the `reset` method before adding each annotation from localstorage.

This is what I added:

```
  function saveAnnotations() {
    localStorage.setItem('annotations', JSON.stringify(anno.getAnnotations()));
  }

  // check for saved annotations
  var storedAnnotations = localStorage.getItem('annotations');
  if (storedAnnotations !== null) {
    anno.reset();  //reinitialize the annotations
    storedAnnotations = JSON.parse(storedAnnotations);

    //restore saved annotations
    storedAnnotations.forEach(function(annotation) {
      anno.addAnnotation(annotation); 
    })
  }

  anno.addHandler('onAnnotationRemoved', saveAnnotations);
  anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated', saveAnnotations);
  anno.addHandler('onAnnotationUpdated', saveAnnotations);
```

This won't run in SO's snippet due to CORS issues with localstorage, so here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jo6hmc7q/

Comment: I am getting the same error with your code too. Image annotation is not working for the second image. Do I need to make any change in browser settings? plz help me.

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet" in xorspark's answer above, does it behave as you expected? If not, can you describe what you see vs what you would like to see? You should never need to change browser-specific settings nor expect your users to.

Comment: @VedPrakash Turns out I missed that the second tab didn't quite work right. I updated my answer. It seems like you need to use a combination of the CSS-based initialization and the API to keep the annotation plugin working when switching tabs. There might be a better way to do this but it at least works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @xorspark.Love you dude, you saved me.

Comment: I need little more help guys, I want to save these notes to local storage and load them back after refresh.

Comment: Can you please replace css tabs to foundation tabs. Actually, our whole project is built on foundation, so css tabs can't be integrated. Furthermore, I am facing errors with callback thing when I am using foundation. Please Please help me.